# What is the meaning and origin of the word/phrase 奥利给?

Tags: vocabulary

I think it means something along the lines of 给力, and I get the impression it is a relatively new word used on the web. Though I can't really understand the explanations online. Can anyone shed some light on this word ?

Comment: Japanese: お願い (please) /O ne gai ; 
Chinese transliteration: 奥利给 /Ào lì gěi/

Comment: @TangHo Are you sure ? Why do you think that ?

Comment: It’s reverse of 給力哦.

Comment: @dROOOze Any idea why it was reversed ? Does it mean the same thing ?

Comment: @Kantura People just invent that because it sounds more imposing. They are the same meaning.

Comment: @AlanZzz Thanks but I don't understand. More imposing than what ? The same meaning as what ?

Answer (score 1):

奥利给's translation is "awesome"，“给力”
The detailed meaning:
No matter what difficulties we encounter, don't be afraid. Face it with a smile. The best way to eliminate fear is to face fear. Perseverance is victory! Come on, 奥利给！
Origin:
有网友将这些口头禅汇集剪辑成了一首舞曲作品，魔性洗脑走红网络。后来经过一系列恶趣味短视频，被大多数人引申为其他意思。（baike (百科)).com
"Some netizens edited these catchphrases into a piece of dance music, and magic brainwashing became popular on the Internet. Later, after a series of short videos, it was extended to other meanings by most people."
Baidu translate

That's all I could find